# Override dataclass __eq__ and __hash__

Tags: python, class, set

Just starting with these kind of techniques and can't figure something out. Say I have:

```
@dataclass
class Number:
     digit: int
```

Now I want numbers whose distance to one another is less than 10 to be equal, so I implement:

```
@dataclass
class Number:
​
    digit: int
​
    def __eq__(self, other):
        
        if np.abs(self.digit - other.digit) < 10:
            return True
        return False
    
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.digit)
```

An example shows that this seems to work:

```
ten = Number(10)
fifteen = Number(15)

ten == fifteen
True
```

Now I create two sets and try to do this intersection:

```
set10 = set([ten])
set15 = set([fifteen])

set10.intersection(set15)
```

The Output is an empty `set()` which I do not expect since the instances are equal. What is going wrong?

Comment: Your definition of `hash` is not consistent with your definition of `__equal__`. `ten` and `fifteen` are "equal", but their hashes are not.

Comment: Yes that is what I assumed. But how do I make their hashes equal? That I can't figure out.

Comment: You can't. Hashes depend on the value alone, whereas equality depends on both values being compared.

Comment: Don't think you can define a hash function that's consistent with your equal definition. You can work around it by defining the hash to return a constant value but that will have adverse performance consequences.

Comment: Your definition of equality isn't really valid, anyway, as it's not transitive. `Number(10) == Number(19)` and `Number(19) == Number(28)`, but `Number(10) != Number(28)`.

Comment: Yes I tried return a constant value but that makes my program way to slow as you already pointed out.
@chepner I do not get that. All these statement evaluate to the right bool. Or what do you mean? Anyway, any suggestion to solve problem somehow elegantly? Or do I need a completly different approach?

Comment: @Jailbone A proper definition of `==` means that `a == b` and `b == c` implies that `a == c`. That's not true of your definition. You should define a *different* method to implement this kind of closeness check instead of redefining `==`.

Comment: Ultimately, `set` does not care about *equality*; it cares about *distinctness*, which is defined by `__hash__`. In general, `a == b` implies that `hash(a) == hash(b)` should also be true, but if `a != b`, it doesn't matter if their hash values are the same or not.

Comment: You are attempting to make the hash value depend on what other values are already in a set.

Comment: Ah ok I get it, thank you! So this is trickier than it seems and I don't see any way at the moment. I'll think about it.